# How to prove the determinant of an antisymmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> If A is a nxn antysimmetric matrix, prove that $(-1)^ndet(A)=det(A)$

I don't really know how to start, I have an idea that I have to use $det(A)=det(A^t)$ since $A^t=-A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to use two rules. The first is the rule connecting $\det(A)$ and $\det(A^T)$, which you already stated correctly and says that $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$.

The second rule is the rule that connects $\det(A)$ and $\det(\lambda A)$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good:

$\det(A)= \det(A^t)=\det(-A)= (-1)^n\det(A)$ and you are done !